# GTK+ Make file - How do I enter the debugging flag?

Tags: debugging, makefile, gtk, flags, kdbg

simple question.
I want to be able to run my executable with a program like ddd or kdbg.
How do I add the debugging flag so that kdbg will show the source code?

My make file macros look like

> CC     = gcc
>
> CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
>
> LIBS   = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

I've tried:

> CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -g

and

> CC     = gcc -g

but neither work. kdbg opens without showing code.

**Fixed:** The problem was that I wasn't deleted the o files, and so the make was just relinking those existing object files without recompiling them.

Comment: The link that you provided is about building Glib itself, most likely you don't have to compile it manually. Please, clarify, whether you want to build Glib or just to link it with you program.

Comment: Yeah, no. All I want to do is include debugging info. Link removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't deleted the o files, and so the make was just relinking those existing object files without recompiling them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow pass [`-g` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) to compiler and linker.

The simplest way is to append it to `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables by adding the following lines to your script:

```
...

ifdef DEBUG

CFLAGS  += -g
LDFLAGS += -g

endif
```

Now one can pass `DEBUG` flag to Make to enable building debuggable binary.

```
make DEBUG=1
```